# I would like to sort rows of a data file by NF increasing

Tags: sorting

I would like to sort rows of a data file by NF increasing.

input

```
z a b c d k l p m
m x y h j i
y w
g t y u
```

output

```
y w
g t y u
m x y h j i
z a b c d k l p m
```

I had tried sort command, but it no works.
How to?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. Share the code.

Comment: And please tell what programming language you're using...

Comment: My programming language is Bourne shell.(in Debian or CentOS).

Comment: When i awk syslog and match what i want, and there are many different NF of log,
For next step to catch ip , i need to know how to cut them.
Here are these part of test codes, but not about sort.
<code>
#!/bin/bash
num=2000
tail -n $num /var/log/syslog |\
awk '/SSL_accept error from unknown && !/smtp:unknown/ && /([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/' > result.log; \
awk '{print NF}' result.log > result_NF.log
</code>

Answer (score 1):

Typically you solve these types of problems by modifying the input stream to add some data, operating on that data, and then removing it. In this case, we want to add the field count to the input stream, sort (numerically) on the field count, and then remove it (using a space as the field delimiter):

```
awk '{ print NF, $0 }' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

You can either pipe your data to `awk` or pass the filename as another argument to `awk`.